# Filters vs. File Paths VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Where I work, there is a significant difference between how the Solution Explorer filters are setup and the filepaths where source files are actually located, which often makes finding source files from in the Solution Explorer difficult when I know where they actually are on my drive.  I've included a link to a screenshot for clarity.

Is there a way to change the the view of the Solution Explorer to show the actual folder structure instead of the file filters?

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvEjG.jpg

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Select the project node and then at the top of Solution Explorer click the "Show All Files" button. (disclaimer: I implemented this feature in VS 2005 for Visual C++).

Note that Solution Explorer will only show sub-directories of the project directory.  Files that are outside of the project directory structure will show up as "links".

Comment: Fantastic, this is is 90% of what I'm looking for, so thank you for that!  Do you know if there is a way to do this for the entire solution and/or make this the default for any opened solution?  When I click on the solution, instead of project, I don't see a "Show All Files" button.

Comment: It's project-specific, unfortunately.  I can't remember off the top of my head if the command will show up when multiple projects are selected, but that might be one way to "easily" turn it on for lots of projects.  Each project should remember the setting.